# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, eclipse, parsing, sdk

I am writing an app intend to run on android devices.The app is supossed to read the information in a Mysql database through php, but when I run the application, Log cat prompts an error 'Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

The code I've got was downloaded from a tutorial, please be patient I've got some basic knowledge in php and very few in java. I already tested the php script and it is working flawlessly, so I won't bother to attach it.

main.java code:

package test.an2mysql;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class main extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

   TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources 
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML. 
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()); 
    txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext()); 
    rootLayout.addView(txt); 
    setContentView(rootLayout); 

    // Set the text and call the connect function. 
    txt.setText("Connecting...");
  //call the method to run the data retreival
    txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121));



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.1.1.19/cms/test/android2mysql/read.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

   InputStream is = null;

   String result = "";
    //the data to send
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("country","undefined"));

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //parse json data
    try{
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                            ", country: "+json_data.getString("country")+
                            ", documentn: "+json_data.getInt("documentn")
                    );
                    //Get an output to the screen
                    returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
       }
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }
    return returnString;
}   

}

I would kindly appreciate any help you could give me.

Comment: Going on the title of you question.. it looks like your trying to parse xml when your code is expecting JSON

Comment: @user1350102: **"I already tested the php script and it is working flawlessly..."** - I beg to differ. The php script may be returning 'something' but it's not working "flawlessly". From your question title, as nz_karl suggests, `<?xml` is the start of an XML declaration which means your php script is returning XML data and not pure JSON.

Comment: am also getting the same problem.. when i try to parse the json url am getting same error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments to your question, it appears that your server is returning XML rather than JSON.  You can easily confirm this by just outputting `result`:

```
}catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    Log.e("log_tag", "Failed data was:\n" + result);
}
```

If it's XML, which it almost certainly must be, then you either need to get the server to output JSON or you need to parse the XML that it's sending you.